# Meteor Accounts.verifyEmail to set role on the user

Tags: meteor

I would like that every user who verifies his email in my app gets a certain role afterwards. I'm using the alanning:roles package. Anyway, after he clicks on the verification link that I have a function that sets a role in in Mongo for him.

so I found this function but its apparently only client side:

```
// (client-side)
Template.Homepage.created = function() {
  if (Accounts._verifyEmailToken) {
    Accounts.verifyEmail(Accounts._verifyEmailToken, function(err) {
      if (err != null) {
        if (err.message = 'Verify email link expired [403]') {
          console.log('Sorry this verification link has expired.')
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Thank you! Your email address has been confirmed.')
      }
    });
  }
};
```

And I have the method for setting roles on the server side

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, ['employer']);

if (options.profile) {
  // include the user profile
  user.profile = options.profile
}
```

How can I connect those two, or is there a better way for implementing this logic. I know this is now in the function "onCreateUser" but would put it seperatly if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the [matb33:collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) package.

Then you can detect changes to the user's collection on the server:

```
var indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

Meteor.users.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
  if (indexOf.call(fieldNames, "emails") >= 0 && doc.emails) {
    doc.emails.forEach(function(email) {
      if (email.verified === true) {
         // Verified address - do something....
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Anyway would there be a solution using the standard call of the Accounts.verifyEmail as i actually just need to use it once and not listen all the time if something changes :)